# Is there a way to generate a matrix in which each element is defined as 10+row_index + column_index without for loops?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to generate a matrix in which each element is defined as 10 * row_index + column_index. The rows and columns may fluctuate up to a 9x9 matrix. For example:

```
11    12    13    14    15    16
21    22    23    24    25    26
31    32    33    34    35    36
41    42    43    44    45    46
51    52    53    54    55    56
```

The algorithm is exceedingly simple with `for` loops, but I've been warned that I should avoid `for` loops unless absolutely necessary, when dealing with matrices, because they are slower than vector/matrix operations.

What other ways are there to generate such a matrix in Matlab 2012b?

Comment: I don't see why this should be downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your particular matrix, it's quite straightforward:

```
nRows = 4;
nCols = 5;

out = bsxfun(@plus,10*(1:nRows)',1:nCols)

out =

11    12    13    14    15
21    22    23    24    25
31    32    33    34    35
41    42    43    44    45
```

Comment: @Ricardoaltamirano: for-loops aren't always slower in more recent versions of Maltab, but in this case, I don't think you can beat `bsxfun`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Jonas. I wasn't aware that the speed of for-loops had been improved in recent versions, so I fell back to my experience with other programs that work with/in matrices, in which loops are almost *always* slower than matrix operations.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano: vectorized operations is still often the way to go. However, simple loops have been benefitted lots from JIT acceleration.